# Plotting Dividing Streamline

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to plot just the dividing streamline of a flow on Maple. I have the complex potential $$\Omega(z)=Uz+\frac{m}{2\pi}ln(z)$$ with Stream function $$\psi(r,\theta)=Ur\sin\theta + \frac{m\theta}{2\pi}$$ I calculated the stagnation points to occur at $$\Omega'(z)=U+\frac{m}{2\pi z}=0$$ Hence occur at $$z=-\frac{m}{2\pi U}$$ I thought to find the dividing streamline, I would set the stream function equal to the stagnation point as this would show the streamline passing through i.e. $$\psi(r,\theta)=Ur\sin\theta + \frac{m\theta}{2\pi} + \frac{m}{2\pi U}=0$$ but I can't seem to get the curve I expect from Maple. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're equating the stream function to the co-ordinate of the stagnation point, not its value there. At $z=-m/(2\pi)$ we have $r = m/(2\pi)$ and $\theta = \pi$. So $\psi(r,\theta) = -U m /(2 \pi) + m/2$. This is the value you need to be equating $\psi$ to.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance I'll give it a go, thanks!

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance so at $z=-m/(2\pi U)$ we have $r=m/(2\pi U)$ and $\theta$= $\pi$. $\psi(r,\theta )= m/2$? Edit: taking m & U=1, I get the dividing streamline I expect, but a few squiggly lines at the stagnation point.